# Openpyxl fails to read row when reference attribute is missing

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to read an excel worksheet. It throws a KeyError when iterating and parsing rows because the openxml row element doesn't have a reference attribute ('r'). It only has a style index ('s') and 'customFormat'.

[Openxml spreadsheet attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell?view=openxml-2.8.1#remarks)

How can I read the cells in this file?

The error occurs whether the workbook is opened as read_only or not, and when referencing cells different ways because they all call `openpyxl.worksheet._reader.parse_row()`

I can't share the excel workbook, but the python code is very simple.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb['Sheet1']
print(ws['A1'])
```

The error:

```
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 150, in parse
    row = self.parse_row(element)
  File "openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py", line 272, in parse_row
    self.row_dimensions[attrs['r']] = attrs
KeyError: 'r'
```

From the debugger:

```
row = {Element} <Element '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}row' at 0x000002713782E9F8>
    attrib = {dict} <class 'dict'>: {'s': '148', 'customFormat': '1'}
    tag = {str} '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}row'
    tail = {NoneType} None
    text = {NoneType} None
```

Comment: I think you'll have to patch the source code for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to downgrade to `openpyxl` version 2.5.14.

One of the developers says that (in 2.6.x versions of `openpyxl`) the `'r'` attribute is required even if the OOXML specs says it is optional. See [this issue opened on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1321/load_workbook-fails-to-open-spreadsheet) for more information.